# Google Anlytics - User Type Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

just a question about a custom dashboard in GA. I'd like to to monitor only help/faq pages in my site. I've created a dashboard that filter only the pages I need vs Unique Page views, but I want a deeper analysis.

For example, does it makes sense to track User Type (new/returning visitors), to know if the user that is viewing my help pages is someone who visit often these pages (like a reference resource to check everytime you need) or if they are mainly new visitors. In this case, it's better to track Sessions vs User type OR Unique Page Views vs User Type?

Inside an help section, can we talk of sessions? Or session is something wider, meaningful only in the whole site perspective?

Answer (score 1):

Unique Page Views vs User Type will show you if the sections are useful to readers and they go deeper.

At the same time, usually, if 1 FAQ page gives a comprehensive answer, the user don't have to keep on hanging around in the section.

Keep it in mind, that GA calculates bounce rate when the user doesn't go to more than 1 page, while 1 page for FAQ is enough if it provides enough data.

Comment: So if 50% are Returning Visitors, maybe they are conscious of this kind of resource and keep it in consideration? And if there is high Bounce Rate, they usually view one single page of the help section? In fact they are single standalone guides with minimal relations to each other.